# GIT Base project code

Tags: git, extjs, frameworks, radix

I just developed an ExtJS base framework for most of my projects.

The problem I have at this moment is that I dont know using GIT, how to have the framework code centralized so every project can share that code.

What I want is that all specific projects can reflect changes made on the framework base code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the framework its own repo, and then have the other project repos add the framework repo as a submodule. Git submodules allow for Git repos to be nested within other Git repos.

There are multiple advantages to this system. First, the framework stays as its own repo, meaning it can be added as a submodule to as many other project repos as you want. Second, as its own repo, it can be updated and versioned separately, keeping the framework separate from the projects using it.

There's more info on Git submodules here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I found it really useful and it solved my problem!!

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! So you know, if this answered your question, you should mark it as the answer (by clicking the checkmark next to it). That way, in the future, people will be able to clearly see the answer to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I did not know about that, I already set it as the answer. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm not sure if the framework is *used* (unmodified) by your projects (i.e. your projects depend on the framework and use it as a library) or the framework is used as a *base* for your projects (i.e. all your projects have the same structure and you want to reuse it).

If it's the first (framework is library), see [ilollars answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958894/1347968).

If it's the second (framework is base structure) you can do something like this: Put your framework in a (central) repository. When you start a new project, clone your framework repository. You are now free to do project specific things in this new repository. When you need to change your framework, first do this in your framework repository, then merge this change to each project repository. Here an example:

```
cd framework
git init
# do your framework development
git add .
git commit
```

Now you have your first framework version. Then start your first project by starting of with the frameworks current version:

```
cd ..
git clone framework project1
cd project1
# do work on your project
git commit
```

Now you need to change something in your framework:

```
cd ../framework
# do the changes
git commit
```

To update your project to the new framework version:

```
cd ../project1
git pull
```

You have now your current framework version with the project specific changes in it :-)

Comment: Nice explanation! It was just what I was looking for, thanks :)